# does IIS 7 treat ASP.NET errors differently than wcf errors?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis-7

when ASP.NET throws an application error, IIS shows the 500 HTML error, but when a WCF service throws a `FaultException` (IIS 500), the client gets a proper SOAP fault with error message in it.

Is there any good documentation on this request processing?

Comment: What type of documentation are you looking for? This how SOAP works.

Comment: its more for iis, why does iis show html page for asp.net but returns soap message for wcf, even though from its perspective both calls are same

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is exactly how SOAP faults works.

> Whenever the code within a Web service raises an exception, ASP.NET catches that exception >and transforms it into a SOAP Fault.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480514.aspx) link for details